# Converting irregularly time stamped Dateframe object, having price and volume information into equally spaced, volume weighted average price

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas, time-series

I have data about price and volume of a stock which is time stamped and irregularly spaced and has duplicate time indexes. A simple example of such a data would be:

```
                       unixtime    price  amount
2011-04-17 01:03:11  1303002191  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:03:14  1303002194  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:03:17  1303002197  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:03:19  1303002199  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:03:21  1303002201  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:03:23  1303002203  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:03:37  1303002217  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:03:45  1303002225  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:03:57  1303002237  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:04:42  1303002282  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:04:55  1303002295  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:05:00  1303002300  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:05:03  1303002303  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:05:11  1303002311  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:05:24  1303002324  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:05:34  1303002334  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:05:45  1303002345  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:05:56  1303002356  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:06:11  1303002371  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:06:25  1303002385  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:06:28  1303002388  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:06:31  1303002391  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:06:33  1303002393  1.02570       1
2011-04-17 01:06:34  1303002394  1.02560       1
2011-04-17 01:06:44  1303002404  1.02560       1
2011-04-17 01:07:02  1303002422  1.02560       2
2011-04-17 01:07:21  1303002441  1.02563       2
2011-04-17 01:07:46  1303002466  1.02563       2
2011-04-17 01:08:24  1303002504  1.02563       2
2011-04-17 01:09:55  1303002595  1.02570       2
2011-04-17 01:10:50  1303002650  1.02570       2
2011-04-17 01:11:02  1303002662  1.02570       2
```

What I want is an equally spaced series of in this case lets say 30 second frequency with volume(amount)-weighted price averages. I have been able to obtain equally spaced 30 seconds intervals and the last price for that particular interval and also the total amount(volume) during that interval, using **how** = "last" and "sum" respectively. But how can I do resampling to get volume weighted-price for 30 sec intervals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I would create a new column for the total sold, and do two resamples:

```
In [11]: df['total'] = df['price'] * df['amount']

In [12]: df.total.resample('30S', how='sum') / df.amount.resample('30S', how='sum')
Out[12]:
2011-04-17 01:03:00    1.025700
2011-04-17 01:03:30    1.025700
2011-04-17 01:04:00         NaN
2011-04-17 01:04:30    1.025700
2011-04-17 01:05:00    1.025700
2011-04-17 01:05:30    1.025700
2011-04-17 01:06:00    1.025700
2011-04-17 01:06:30    1.025650
2011-04-17 01:07:00    1.025615
2011-04-17 01:07:30    1.025630
2011-04-17 01:08:00    1.025630
2011-04-17 01:08:30         NaN
2011-04-17 01:09:00         NaN
2011-04-17 01:09:30    1.025700
2011-04-17 01:10:00         NaN
2011-04-17 01:10:30    1.025700
2011-04-17 01:11:00    1.025700
Freq: 30S, dtype: float64
```

*Assuming this is the thing you want...*

Comment: @user1434997 please tick this answer (on the left) if it's solved the problem :)